# for numbers outside range, short type casting gives overflow, but long type casting gives compile error?

Tags: java

```
/*Casting to short via (short)# gives overflow, but casting to long via (long)# gives compile error.  Am I missing something fundamental? (I'm a new student, still learning where educational resources are)
*/

//I'm working in Intellij IDEA.

short y = (short)198_203_304;

long t = (long)1_923_123_456_789_000;  
// won't compile as number is outside long range

long u = 1_923_123_456_789_000L;  
// use of #L casts to long, but I understand risk of data loss is   
// present.

System.out.println("y = " + y);
System.out.println("u = " + u);

//... yields...

y = 20473
// Result of overflow, since 198_203_304 is out of range, I believe.
u = 1923123456789000
```

/*So my question is why wouldn't the use of long u = (long)#### result in overflow instead of compile error, as the situation with short did?
*/

Answer (score 2):

```
short y = (short)198_203_304;
```

198_203_304 is literal type int. You're in range for that. No compiler error!

```
long t = (long)1_923_123_456_789_000;
```

1_923_123_456_789_000 is literal type int. You're out of range for that - compiler error!

```
long u = 1_923_123_456_789_000L;
```

"1_923_123_456_789_000L" is literal type long. You're in range for that - no compiler error!

See [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html) and the section "Integer Literals".

Comment: But 198_203_304 is cast as short, and it's out of range for short.  The result shown above (y = 20473) is the result of overflow, I believe.

Comment: (long)1_923_123_456_789_000 is cast as long and is out of range.  I would expect that to result in the same overflow condition as the short y = (short)198_203_304;

Comment: And if long t = (long)1_923_123_456_789_000 is cast as long, and long u = 1_923_123_456_789_000 is cast as long, why don't they give the same result?